# Insertion Sort assembly code (Translated from C)

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, assembly, insertion-sort

I don't have deep knowledge of *assembly programming*.

I am trying to translate the following code from *Pure C* to *Assembly language*.

**Pure-C**

```
int i,j,temp;
for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
{
    temp = global_array[i];
    for ( j = i-1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
    {
        if ( global_array[j] <= temp ) break; //if first value is bigger than the second value
            global_array[j+1] = global_array[j];
    }
    global_array[j+1]=temp;
}
```

*Please, check how well did I translate from Pure C to Assembly language?*

**ASM**

```
.globl _Sort
//.type AtoI,@function

//Declaration of variables
.comm _global_array,40 //this is an array of integers
.comm _temp,4 //this is the variable temp
.comm _i,4 //used for loop
.comm _j,4 //used for loop



_Sort:
/*prolog*/
pushl %ebp
pushl %ebx
movl %esp, %ebp //move the special ptr to base ptr
subl $8, %esp //allocate space for the variables local_var and temp_var

pushl %esi //index register
pushl %edi //index register


/*put code here*/
//for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
//first for loop
movl $0, _i //index i = 0

ForOne:
movl _i, %eax
movl _i, %esi //move i into index register
cmp $10, %eax //if i is less than or equal 9, continue this loop
jge return
movl _global_array, %ebx
movl (%ebx,%esi,4), _%ecx
movl %ecx, _temp //temp = global_array[i]
movl _i, %eax //i-1
subl $1, %eax
movl %eax, _j //move j into index register
jmp ForTwo //jump to second for loop

ForTwo:
movl _j, %eax
cmp $0, %eax //j >= 0
jl ForOneFn //get out of 2nd loop to end of 1st loop
movl _global_array, %ebx
cmp _temp, (%ebx,%edi,4) //if ( global_array[j] <= temp ) break;
jle ForOneFn //jump to end of first loop after break
movl (%ebx,%edi,4),%ecx
addl $1,%eax //j+1
movl _j, %edi //move j into index register 
movl _global_array, %ebx
movl %ecx, (%ebx,%edi,4) //global_array[j+1] = global_array[j];

//last line of code is jump to reloop/finish 2nd loop
jmp ForTwoFn

ForTwoFn:
subl $1, _j
jmp ForTwo

ForOneFn:
addl $1, _i
jmp ForOne


return:
/*epilog*/
movl %ebp,%esp
popl %ebx
popl %ebp
ret
```

Comment: The question is, have you tried it? Does it work? If not, what's the behavior?

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Just as importantly, does the C code even work?  Line 8 is indented such that it appears to belong inside line 7's `if` block, but it actually isn't.

Comment: @AaronDufour The code is correct there, the indentation isn't.

Comment: it doesn't work because I face some compilation problems like too much memory references to 'mov'....I hope I can find some mistakes in my array codes..

Comment: You could use a C compiler to translate to assembly, e.g. GCC with the -S option. It will probably generate some constructs you don't want, but you can clean it up manually.

Comment: Please do not mutilate your question.  If you need to amend it, or emphasize something, by all means edit it, but do not destroy the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First advice: use registers more intensively.

You have 2 index variables, temporary variable and global_array address, so you have enough registers.

Code should compile if line:

```
cmp _temp, (%ebx,%edi,4) //if ( global_array[j] <= temp ) break;
```

will be replaced by:

```
cmp eax, (%ebx,%edi,4) //if ( global_array[j] <= temp ) break;, where eax is yours temp
```

If you code this routine using registers only it will be smaller and easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Thanks! I manage to compile it now. However I am receiving bus errors. Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: Probably one of your index (i or j) variables goes out of array range (beyond lower, 0, or upper bound) and your code accesses memory not belonging to program. I suggests validating loop indexes commissions and conditional jumps.